# Alignment of dynamic divs

Tags: html, css, alignment, fluid-layout

What should I do with the dynamic div boxes so that it will automatically move in two column where space available as per grab?

The order of boxes is like:

1. UND: Understanding energy
2. EP1: Reservoirs and geology
3. EP2: Exploration i
4. EP3: Exploration ii and so on

Its already float left and its parent div has fixed width to show these into two column. I also applied clear both (`div.column:nth-child(odd){ clear:both;}`) on odd elements, Third one goes down in correct position but fourth div not works. Fourth one has lots of space from top.

Thanks
Dipender Singh

[image: Div alinment]

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to add the child div's to a single main div.
then add a float left css property for all the child div's
something like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left">What ever content</div>
    <div style="float:left">What ever content</div>
    <div style="float:left">What ever content</div>
    <div style="float:left">What ever content</div>
    <div style="float:left">What ever content</div>
</div>
```

Just note that depending on the width of the screen and the width of the individual child div's this solution will not limit the amount of columns to only two. So if you only want two columns you should consider adding a max-width style to the main div, which will limit the columns to only two.